# Getting up and running with a Stellar-Core and Horizon with a Database

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, postgres

I am new to the Stellar world and wanted to set up a node (Stellar Core, Horizon and a Database) for the first time to run as an anchor. However, I couldn't figure it out from the documentation how to do it. There are docker image and exe files but I couldn't make any of them. I don't know how to set up and use the three components i.g. Stellar core, Horizon and a database? For example, how to run them, where to host them, how to access them and how to configure them in Ubuntu/Windows/Cloud? Your responses will be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of installing stellar-core and stellar-horizon, Docker images, Apt packages (apt-get install), compile from source.

If you have access to a Ubuntu machine running 16.04 you can follow the instructions available https://github.com/stellar/packages/blob/master/README.md, the `stellar-quickstart` may be of interest to you for a Testnet watcher.

You can also use the docker `stellar-quickstart` image, documentation is https://hub.docker.com/r/stellar/quickstart/

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for providing the links. This is exactly my problem as those documentations are not clear to a new user. For example, I don't know how to set up the database and connect it to the Stellar Core or Horizon and also how to set up the stellar core and horizon itself.